# Regular expression for 3 decimal point

Tags: asp.net, regex

I need a regular expression that satisfy these rules:

1. The maximum number of decimal point is 3 but a number with no decimal point (e.g 12) should be accepted too
2. the value must be at least 0
3. the value must be less or equal to 99999999999.999
4. the radix point is DOT (e.g 2.5, not 2,5)

**Sample of valid numbers:**

```
0
2
0.4
78784764.23
45.232
```

**Sample of invalid numbers:**

```
-2
123456789522144
84.2564
```

I found an example here (http://forums.asp.net/t/1642501.aspx) and have managed to modify it a little bit to make 0 as the minimum value, 99999999999.999 as the maximum value and to accept only DOT as radix point. Here's my modified regex:

```
^\-?(([0-9]\d?|0\d{1,2})((\.)\d{0,2})?|99999999999.999((\.)0{1,2})?)$
```

However, I still have problem with the 3 decimal point and it is rather unstable. Can anyone help me on this since I'm basically illiterate when it comes to regex?

Thanks.

**EDITED:**
I'm using ASP Regular Expression Validator

Comment: Why are you allowing a minus sign if the minimum value is 0?

Comment: I do not plan to allow minus sign, but since the user will be entering the input in a textbox so there is a possibility that the user will try to input a negative value (as well as non numeric value).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is not that difficult:

```
^[0-9]{1,11}(?:\.[0-9]{1,3})?$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^            # Start of string
[0-9]{1,11}  # Match 1-11 digits (i. e. 0-99999999999)
(?:          # Try to match...
 \.          # a decimal point
 [0-9]{1,3}  # followed by one to three digits (i. e. 0-999)
)?           # ...optionally
$            # End of string
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm sorry but it doesn't seem to work. I tested with this value, 54.866 and the validation failed. It also failed when the value is 100 or more. It works for these values: 58, 1.2, 1.23 though

Comment: That regex [absolutely works](https://gist.github.com/3826240) with `54.866` here.

Comment: @ixora: Tim's regex works perfectly.  It's the regex in your question that fails in the way you describe.  BTW, the reason your adapted regex is so complicated is because the original didn't allow leading zeroes and it *did* allow a minus sign (neither of which was among the stated requirements) and it had to match `200` or `200.00` but not `200.01` or `200.99`.  Your case is much simpler.

Comment: I tested with Tim's regex again this morning and it works. I don't know why it wasn't working when I tested it yesterday and I haven't made any changes in between. That being said, sorry for the inconveniences caused and thank you everyone for helping me.

Comment: Thanks for "Explanation"

Comment: it's good but doesn't handle number starts with 0 but not follow by decimal point like 01.2

Comment: `^[0-9]{1,11}(?:\.([0-9]{1,3})?)?$` allows typed inputs and/or terminating in a period